# Nested booleans in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to convert the javascript found at https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile from JS over to TypeScript.

I'm doing ok so far, but have gotten to this block of code:

```
    this.apple = {
        phone:  match(apple_phone, ua),
        ipod:   match(apple_ipod, ua),
        tablet: !match(apple_phone, ua) && match(apple_tablet, ua),
        device: match(apple_phone, ua) || match(apple_ipod, ua) || match(apple_tablet, ua)
    };
```

I declared "apple" as a boolean in my class using

```
 class IsMobileService {
     public apple: boolean;
```

The problem is, I am getting "Cannot convert type '{phone: boolean; ipod:boolean;tablet:boolean;device:boolean}' to type 'boolean'" as an error.

I also tried declaring

```
public apple.phone: boolean;
```

in the declaration section, but am told that I have a duplicate identifier 'apple' in the code.

Ideally, a user should just be able to call IsMobileService.apple or IsMobileService.apple.phone to get the info they need.

Answer (score 0):

`apple` isn't a boolean.  its an `Object`.

Simplest thing would be to just use it as an object, like:

```
public apple:Object = {
    phone:  match(apple_phone, ua),
    ipod:   match(apple_ipod, ua),
    tablet: !match(apple_phone, ua) && match(apple_tablet, ua),
    device: match(apple_phone, ua) || match(apple_ipod, ua) || match(apple_tablet, ua)
};
```

But if you want to be more strict (to require `apple` to be an object composed of specific booleans) then you could use an `interface`, like:

```
export interface Apple {
    phone:boolean;
    ipod:boolean;
    ...
}
```

and set `apple` to type `Apple` instead of `object`, like:

```
public apple:Apple = {
    phone:  match(apple_phone, ua),
    ipod:   match(apple_ipod, ua),
    tablet: !match(apple_phone, ua) && match(apple_tablet, ua),
    device: match(apple_phone, ua) || match(apple_ipod, ua) || match(apple_tablet, ua)
};
```

When trying to check the property, you'd then use the instance of your IsMobileService class, reach in to it's public apple object, and grab the property you want to examine.

Comment: The only issue is that a user could not just call apple to see if any of the four booleans are true.

Comment: Never mind. I realized the dev of the original script didn't do that either. He used apple.device to test for that.

Comment: To do that, you'd just add a method to the interface, or to the isMobileService class to check that, and call that method.